# Rails 5 ActionCable Works using DIV, but not UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, actioncable

I have created a WebSocket messaging feature using Rails 5 ActionCable. It works great when I use a DIV as the container. But when I changed it to use a UL and LI instead; it stopped working. I cant seem to debug this; but it looks like the `received:` event is not being trigger on the client.  The send_message works...and is saved in the database, its just new messages do not appear on the page.

**TL;DR; bit at the bottom of the question.**

---

### UPDATE

**I have managed to diagnose the problem, it works again when i remove the lines (from the _message.html.erb partial) that check against the current_user `message.user == current_user` - but why?**

---

Help would be greatly appreciated. Here is (I think) all the relevant code:

#### /app/assets/javascripts/channels/conversations.coffee

```
jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  messages = $('#messages')
  if $('#messages').length > 0
    messages_to_bottom = -> messages.scrollTop(messages.prop("scrollHeight"))

    messages_to_bottom()

    App.global_chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
      channel: "ConversationsChannel"
      conversation_id: messages.data('conversation-id')
    },
      connected: ->
        # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

      disconnected: ->
        # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

      received: (data) ->
        messages.append data['message']
        messages_to_bottom()

      send_message: (message, conversation_id) ->
        @perform 'send_message', message: message, conversation_id: conversation_id


    $('#new_message').submit (e) ->
      $this = $(this)
      textarea = $this.find('#message_body')
      if $.trim(textarea.val()).length > 1
        App.global_chat.send_message textarea.val(), messages.data('conversation-id')
        textarea.val('')
      e.preventDefault()
      return false
```

#### /app/channels/conversations_channel.rb

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file. Action Cable runs in a loop that does not support auto reloading.
class ConversationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "conversations_#{params['conversation_id']}_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def send_message(data)
    current_user.messages.create!(body: data['message'], conversation_id: data['conversation_id'], user: current_user)
  end
end
```

#### /app/jobs/message_broadcast_job.rb

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "conversations_#{message.conversation.id}_channel",
                                 message: render_message(message)
  end

  private

  def render_message(message)
    MessagesController.render partial: 'messages/message', locals: {message: message}
  end
end
```

#### /app/views/conversations/show.html.erb

```
...

  <div id="messages" data-conversation-id="<%= @conversation.id %>">
    <ul class="list-unstyled media-block messages-list" data-conversation-id="<%= @conversation.id %>">
    <%= render @conversation.messages %>
    </ul>
  </div>

...

  <div class="row">
    <%= form_for @message, url: '#' do |f| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'conversation_id', @conversation.id %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :body %>
          <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control' %>
          <small class="text-muted">From 2 to 1000 characters</small>
        </div>

        <%= f.submit "Post", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

...
```

#### /app/views/messages/_message.html.erb

```
<% if message.body %>

    <li class="mar-btm message" data-id="<%= message.id %>">
      <div class="<%= message.user == current_user ? 'media-right' : 'media-left' %>">
        <img src="<%= message.user.avatar.url %>" class="img-circle img-sm" alt="Profile Picture">
      </div>
      <div class="media-body pad-hor
        <% if message.user == current_user %>speech-right
        <% end %>">
        <div class="speech">
          <h4><%= message.user.full_name %></h4>
          <%= message.body %>
          <p class="speech-time">
            <i class="demo-pli-clock icon-fw"></i>
            <span class="timestamp" data-value="<%= message.created_at %>"><%= time_ago_in_words message.created_at %>
              ago</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

<% end %>
```

#### TL;DR;

As I said, previously i was using a container div: `<div id="messages" data-conversation-id="<%= @conversation.id %>">` and each message was in a child DIV instead of a LI element, and it was working.  I cant figure out what I broke (or why it matters).

When I post a new message it is send and saved to the database, but it doesn't get sent to the browser.  The logs look like this though:

```
[ActionCable] [an...ey@gmail.com] ConversationsChannel#send_message({"message"=>"23r23r2", "conversation_id"=>5})
[ActionCable] [an...ey@gmail.com]    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
[ActionCable] [an...ey@gmail.com]   SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("conversation_id", "user_id", "body", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["conversation_id", 5], ["user_id", 7], ["body", "23r23r2"], ["created_at", 2017-03-01 01:16:25 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-01 01:16:25 UTC]]
[ActionCable] [an...ey@gmail.com]    (0.9ms)  COMMIT
[ActionCable] [an...ey@gmail.com] [ActiveJob] Enqueued MessageBroadcastJob (Job ID: a464e290-f23f-4cd4-a355-e364a43782e9) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x007ff678cf74e0 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://itpo/Message/172>>
  Message Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 172], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [a464e290-f23f-4cd4-a355-e364a43782e9] Performing MessageBroadcastJob from Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x007ff679dcc400 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://itpo/Message/172>>
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [a464e290-f23f-4cd4-a355-e364a43782e9]   Conversation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE "conversations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [a464e290-f23f-4cd4-a355-e364a43782e9]   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [a464e290-f23f-4cd4-a355-e364a43782e9]   Rendered messages/_message.html.erb (16.6ms)
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [a464e290-f23f-4cd4-a355-e364a43782e9] Performed MessageBroadcastJob from Async(default) in 28.37ms
```

And since the last line of the log says `Performed MessageBroadcastJob from Async(default)` it leads me to believe that the problem doesn't exist on the server side, and that **perhaps my coffee script is broken somehow**.

Maybe the way you insert new elements into a UL is different to just appending HTML onto a DIV?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the _message.html.erb partial view, which was doing a comparison on the 'current_user' from Devise. I guess the WebSocket being stateless doesn't have the same range of access to the user's session data that the view would have under regular conditions. To compensate I added data attributes tot he relevant DOM elements and created a special JavaScript function to apply the differentiating styles and the transform the data into the desired way.  It seems to work flawlessly now.